# "ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree" when installing npm react-facebook-login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Trying to install `npm react-facebook-login` in my react app, but I keep getting dependency errors? That sounds scary and I don't want to force install something that can potentially break in the future. I'm new to javascript, what are some ways I should proceed?

I've tried clearing my npm cache and removing node modules and installing them again, however im still getting this error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: buckets@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-facebook-login@4.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-facebook-login
npm ERR!   react-facebook-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-01-03T12_23_40_000Z-debug.log
```

`debug log`:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'react-facebook-login' ]
1 info using npm@7.0.15
2 info using node@v15.4.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 4ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 12ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 12ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:/home/user/app/frontend/buckets/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/home/user/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 21ms
19 verbose npm-session a80715ea0624d48b
20 timing npm:load Completed in 30ms
21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
22 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1531ms
23 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
24 silly idealTree buildDeps
25 silly fetch manifest react-facebook-login@*
26 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-facebook-login 2249ms
27 silly fetch manifest react@^17.0.1
28 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 142ms
29 timing idealTree Completed in 3940ms
30 timing command:install Completed in 3944ms
31 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
31 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1045:25)
31 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1025:36)
31 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:781:11)
31 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:209:7)
31 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
31 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:122:5)
31 verbose stack     at async install (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:39:3)
32 verbose cwd /home/user/app/frontend/buckets
33 verbose Linux 5.4.0-58-generic
34 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "react-facebook-login"
35 verbose node v15.4.0
36 verbose npm  v7.0.15
37 error code ERESOLVE
38 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
39 error
40 error While resolving: [1mbuckets[22m@[1m0.1.0[22m
40 error Found: [1mreact[22m@[1m17.0.1[22m[2m[22m
40 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
40 error   [1mreact[22m@"[1m^17.0.1[22m" from the root project
40 error
40 error Could not resolve dependency:
40 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m^16.0.0[22m" from [1mreact-facebook-login[22m@[1m4.1.1[22m[2m[22m
40 error [2mnode_modules/react-facebook-login[22m
40 error   [1mreact-facebook-login[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
40 error
40 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
40 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
40 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
40 error
40 error See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
41 verbose exit 1
```

How can I overcome this without causing any future problems? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

This error comes from version 7.x of npm. Please try again adding the `--legacy-peer-deps` option, as follows:

```
npm install react-facebook-login --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: adding --legacy-peer-deps at then end of command worked for me.

Comment: Thank You, This Worked for me. I got error "ERESOLVE" when installing npm i simplebar-react package. So installed this way - npm i simplebar-react --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: happening with Node 18.x too. Thanks!

Comment: npm version 8.18.0 still have this error

Comment: This does seem to fix the problem, but could someone explain why?  And are there any repercussions when using `--legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Answered my own question by finding another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh

Answer (score 16):

Since `npm install` seems broken I,ve tried:

```
yarn install
```

And it works!

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I face this challenge too, and I was trying to run my react.js application.

I have solved it by running:   ***npm install --legacy-peer-deps***

After It started as normal

Answer (score 6):

Use this at the end  --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

Eg:-

```
npm install --force
```

or

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: and on azure pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

I started getting the error (below) after upgrading `npm` from version 6 to 7.

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree
>
> ...
>
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

In my case, using either `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` resulted in a useless bundle.

So I tried deleting the `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and bundle using `yarn install`. This generated a yarn.lock file and created a new package-lock.json that seemed to work fine in subsequent npm runs.

p.s. This is a temporary workaround until `npm` 7 works fine. After that, I will delete yarn.lock, package-lock.json and node_modules, and re-bundle using `npm`.

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json 
yarn install 
# generates a yarn.lock file and a new package-lock.json

# continue with npm 
npm start
```

Answer (score 3):

Its help me to resolve this error

```
npm install --f
```

or use

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

on the command, you are running just add on this  `--legacy-peer-deps`

for me, the command was

```
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux
```

then I added

```
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux --legacy-peer-deps
```

and then boom it works

Answer (score 2):

Try running

`npm update`

especially if the error is a result of a firebase package that may be having a version that is outdated thus conflicting with its peers. Solved my issue as suggested by @snehal

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
npm install angular-google-charts --legacy-peer-deps
```

or like this, if you want to save:

```
npm install --save angular-google-charts --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 1):

`react-facebook-login@4.1.1` package requires `react@^16.0.0` as its peer dependency, but you have installed `react@^17.0.1`. The version is incompatible. The warning will display when using npm v7+

Let's check the peer dependencies of `react-facebook-login@4.1.1` package:

```
$ npm view react-facebook-login@4.1.1 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.0.0' }
```

So the safe solution is to downgrade the `react` package to `^16.0.0`.

```
$ npm i react@^16.0.0 -S

added 2 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 7 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Then, install `react-facebook-login` package:

```
$ npm i react-facebook-login -S

added 1 package, and audited 8 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The warning is gone. List the installed packages:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
peer-deps-issue@ /home/lindu/workspace/peer-deps-issue
├── react-facebook-login@4.1.1
└── react@16.14.0
```

The last publish time of the `react-facebook-login` package is 5 years ago and its latest version is `4.1.1`. It may be outdated and not compatible with `React 17.0.x` .

`React 17` has some break changes, see [Other Breaking Changes](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#other-breaking-changes).

Please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, as it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

You need to make sure the `react-facebook-login@4.1.1` is compatible with `React 17` before using the `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` options.

From npm docmutation [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Use of legacy-peer-deps is not recommended, as it will not enforce the peerDependencies contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while working with a **Face Detection** app in which I had to capture the image using **react-native-camera**.

Although my package was different as per this StackOverflow question but the situation of error is the same.

So, the solution is I added **-legacy-peer-deps** with the npm install  like this:

**npm install @react-native-community/image-editor --save -legacy-peer-deps**

It resolved my issue. Hope you'll get this helpful.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```py
@react-native-firebase/app@12.6.1
├── @react-native-firebase/auth@12.6.1
├── @react-native-firebase/firestore@12.7.1
```

Notice that firestore has a version of `12.7.1` and all other has `12.6.1`, as firestore is a peer of other modules, to maintain consistency, it is also ought to be of the same version as it's peers, when that doesn't happens then you result in the error you have mentioned,

until the first number of the version doesn't changes, you can use --legacy-peer-deps and the result will be somewhat above [get the list of packages installed using `npm ls --depth=0`,

however if you want all of them to be of the same version, you can do the following

- type `npm update` and all the packages will be updated to the latest version, the version will be mostly in which the second number changes. you can also use `npm update` with the specific package to only update the one you want to in order to resolve the error.
- install the specific version of the module by `npm install [package-name]@[version-number]`

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `--force` help me to resolve this error.

```
yarn install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck running **npm install** but didn't work. Then I used the **--legacy-peer-deps** along with npm install command. It resolved my problem.

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

Because `react-facebook-login@4.1.1` necessitates `react@^16.0.0` as its peer dependency, and you currently have `react@17.0.1` installed in your project, this warning has been triggered.

**Option 1:**
To resolve this issue, consider downgrading your React version from `17.0.1` to `^16.0.0`, and then proceed to reinstall `react-facebook-login`.

**Option 2:**
Alternatively, you can force the installation of `react-facebook-login` using either of the following commands:

```
npm install react-facebook-login -S --force

npm install react-facebook-login -S --legacy-peer-deps
```

**Option 3:**
Another approach is to use `npm i @greatsumini/react-facebook-login` instead of the standard `npm i react-facebook-login`. This package may offer compatibility with your current React version.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code , and you should be fine:

npm install --save react-typical --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: What does that do? Please [edit] and explain.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are trying to install the packages into a wrong file path.

Answer (score -1):

For me works removing node_modules and run:

```
npm install
```