# React native npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR?

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

**npm install not working I am facing this error logs**

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!

```
 npm ERR! While resolving:xxx@0.0.1
    npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR! react@"17.0.2" from the root project
    npm ERR! peer react@"*" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
    npm ERR! react-native-country-picker-modal@"^2.0.0" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
    npm ERR! peer react-dom@"*" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree" when installing npm react-facebook-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549858/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-when-installing-npm-react-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved this error by using**

```
npm install --force 
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

> or

we can use `yarn install` in some cases yarn works